# Model.send(...) = [1,2,3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to append some array to model field that i can't write directly.

For example, I need in *block* with `|type|` param code, like this:

```
Employee.find_by(resposible: true).send("#{type}_ids") = [1,2,3]
```

But, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's issue with the syntax you are using. This is the correct syntax for [**`send`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
send(symbol [, args...])
```

So, changing your code to the following should work

```
Employee.find_by(resposible: true).send("#{type}_ids=", [1,2,3])
```

You need to pass the parameters after the comma

**NOTE:** Prefer [**`public_send`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send) over [**`send`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-send), As `public_send` will only invoke public methods unlike `send`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for including parameters in a method called via `send` is a bit different. Try this:

```
Employee.find_by(resposible: true).send("#{type}_ids=", [1,2,3])
```